# Parsear variable String a variable Int en Java

Tags: java, parsear

Estoy practicando los cambios de variable en Java utilizando Eclipse y me ha surgido una pequeña duda .Si quiero cambiar una variable de tipo String a otra de tipo entero (int), ¿cual de la dos formas es la correcta o adecuada para hacerlo?

```
int variable = Integer.parseInt(variableString);
```

ó

```
int variable = Integer.valueOf(variableString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se podría decir ambos métodos pueden utilizarse sin considerar una más "correcto o adecuado" que el otro. Pero, ya que la variable donde vas a almacenar el valor es de un tipo primitivo, yo preferiría utilizar `parseInt()` ya que `valueOf()` creará un objeto innecesario en memoria.

De todos modos, puedes utilizar cualquiera, ya que los mecanismos de autoboxing y auto-unboxing se aseguran de transformar un tipo primitivo a su correspondiente wrapper, o viceversa, cuando sea necesario.

Comment: Para añádir que al hacer análisis estático del código, muchas veces te saldrá que es mejor usar `parseInt()`. Lo explican en esta respuesta de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32516986/236345

Comment: Es correcto, y eso se debe precisamente a lo que comento en mi respuesta, a que si se utiliza `valueOf()`, se estará creando un objeto innecesario en memoria además de que implica la ejecución del mecanismo de auto-unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Si esta completamente seguro que el valor que vas a transformar es de tipo `int` deberías de utilizar:

```
Integer.parseInt(variableValor);
```

Esto debido a que el método regresa un tipo de dato primitivo `int`

Aquí las firmas de los métodos:

```
public static Integer valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException { ... }
...
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException { ... }
```

La diferencia entre los dos métodos es que `Integer.parseInt(String s)` regresa un tipo de dato primitivo `int` y `Integer.valueOf(String s)` regresa un objeto de tipo `Integer`.